# Making an ID system for objects in C#

Tags: c#, class

Im trying to make a program about books, and it needs and ID system. I want to get the access to the information about a specifict object with the book ID. For example:

```
Console.Write("What ID is the book ")
//tempId = **ID**
int tempId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(book**ID**.title); //.title = the title of the book
```

How can I do something like that?

I thought about doing that with a static class atribute, but I'm pretty sure this isn't possible.

Comment: You would need to have a store of books somewhere with a lookup by ID.  If you're trying to do this in memory, a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) design would make the most sense for a lookup by ID.   In .NET, one implementation of this is a Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do would be to create a class "book" containing the attributes you need (id, name, publication date...) and store all these books in an array of type map with the id as primary key. I do not know if I solve your question with this, if your question was not this one, ask me again the question and I will try to help you.

This would be an example of the class "book":

```
#include <string>

class Book {
 public:
  Book(int id, std::string name, std::string publicationDate)
      : id_(id), name_(name), publicationDate_(publicationDate) {}

  int id() const { return id_; }
  std::string name() const { return name_; }
  std::string publicationDate() const { return publicationDate_; }

 private:
  int id_;
  std::string name_;
  std::string publicationDate_;
};
```

And so you can create the map I was telling you about:

```
int main() {
  std::map<int, Book> library;
  library[123] = Book(123, "El Quijote", "1605-01-01");
  library[456] = Book(456, "Cien años de soledad", "1967-05-01");
  library[789] = Book(789, "Don Juan Tenorio", "1844-01-01");

  int bookId = 456;
  auto it = library.find(bookId);
  
  return 0;
}
```

The above code creates a map with three books and retrieves in it the one with id 456.

Comment: Your idea of using an array to store books really helped me, but the code you just posted is in C++ according to ChatGPT (i used it to explain the code since I'm a beginner). Thanks either way!

Comment: Do you need it in c without ++? You are right I did it in c++, whenever I hear c, I usually write it in c++. Do you still need help?